# How do I protect against file corruption when using robocopy restartable mode?

Tags: powershell, deployment, web-deployment, robocopy

I have a powershell script that that copies published files for a web app to a server for deployment. It utilizes robocopy to copy the files. Due to lack of administrator privileges, I can only use restartable mode (/z) and not restartable mode with backup mode (/zb). My question is two parts:

How reliable is robocopy using restartable mode- how likely are files to become corrupted?

What would be the best way to incorporate into the script a check to see whether a file has corrupted during the copying process?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
robocopy /s /z /ndl /r:0 /w:0 /mt:32 .\Publish "DESTINATION_HERE" /MIR
```

Comment: robocopy is very reliable, so long as you have a stable network connection, and the files are reasonably sized (<1GB).  For verification, simply gather the file hashes using `Get-FileHash` of each file before and after the file copy.  If the file hashes match, you're in good shape!

Comment: Unfortunately network connection stability is a concern - thank you for this suggestion, looks like a solid way to verify whether a file has corrupted!